# How can I escape a string to ensure that it is a valid string literal in JS source?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I have a Qt application that embeds a web browser (`QWebEngineView`). I would like to call a javascript function with a string argument from the C++ application. The means of doing this is calling

```cpp
page()->runJavaScript("setContent(\"hello\");");
```

This works in simple cases. However, if I try and load, say, a C++ source file and use that as the parameter of `setContent`, this will break, because I can't simply assemble the string like this:

```cpp
auto js = QString("setContent(\"%1\");").arg(fileStr);
```

I tried the following:

```cpp
fileStr = fileStr.replace('"', "\\\"");
fileStr = fileStr.replace("\n", "\\n");
```

But apparently this could not escape the string, I get an error when I call this javascript. How can I universally escape a long string with newlines and possible special characters so that I can construct a valid js fragment like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some research, I came across [QWebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html) which is meant for bi-directional communication between the application and the hosted webpage. The imported qwebchannel.js in the examples can be found [here](https://github.com/qt/qtwebchannel/blob/dev/src/webchannel/qwebchannel.js). From there, this is what I did:

In C++:

```
  auto channel = new QWebChannel(this);
  page()->setWebChannel(channel);
  channel->registerObject("doc", Doc);
```

In HTML/JS:

```
   new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport,
       function(channel) {
         var doc = channel.objects.doc; // this is "doc" from the registerObject call
         editor.setValue(doc.text);
         doc.textChanged.connect(updateText); // textChanged is a signal of the class of doc.
       }
   );
```

So, even though this does not directly answer the question, what is presented here can be used to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`QJsonDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsondocument.html) to encode the string as a JSON string, since valid JSON strings are also valid Javascript strings.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to get only the string, but instead you can get an array of one element containing the string, from which you can easily extract the string in Javascript by using `[0]` (alternatively, if you need the escaped string as is in C++, you can use a regex to remove the first `[` and the last `]`).

Here is an example:

```cpp
const QString stringToBeEscaped = "A string with \"quotes\"\nand newlines";
const QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(QStringList{stringToBeEscaped});
QString escapedString = QString::fromUtf8(jsonDoc.toJson());
qDebug() << escapedString;  //"[\n    \"A string with \\\"quotes\\\"\\nand newlines\"\n]\n"
escapedString += "[0]";     //To extract the string from the array Javascript-side

page()->runJavaScript(QString("alert(%1)").arg(escapedString));
```